# VSIX - Cannot load assembly of a referenced dll (VisualStudio 2015)

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2015, vsix, vsixmanifest

i have referenced MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf.dll and MaterialDesigncolors.Wpf.dll to the newly created VSIX project in VisualStudio 2015. then i added below code between Grid Tags

```
 <Grid.Resources>
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Light.xaml"></ResourceDictionary>
                    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Defaults.xaml" />
                    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignColors;component/Themes/Recommended/Primary/MaterialDesignColor.DeepPurple.xaml" />
                    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignColors;component/Themes/Recommended/Accent/MaterialDesignColor.Lime.xaml" />
                </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </Grid.Resources>
```

it builds successfully, but when run i get an exception saying,

> Set property 'System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.Source' threw an
>   exception. Inner Exception Could not load file or assembly
>   'MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf

even i cannot add my own classlibrary (class1.dll)

your assistance in this matter is greatly appreciated

Comment: Did you use an an x86 compiled library and are on x64 or vice versa?

Comment: @lokusking x86,even it not works with class library that build it with the same configuration. it can reference but cant use.

Comment: Have you added this dll as nuget-package or similar or did you add it by hand? Sounds like a underlying dll is missing

Comment: Added as nugget,as dll and also added as new project . Nothing works

Comment: Have a look [here](https://github.com/ButchersBoy/MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit/issues/427)